# When profiling lines of jQuery code, does it include rendering time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, profiling

Suppose I am measuring the time it takes to execute a jQuery function such as:

```
<Start timer here>
$("#myImage").hide();
<End timer here>
```

Within that timer code, does it include any reflows or repaints that occur as a result of calling that method? Or does that happen some time afterwards (i.e. a message gets posted to a queue and then gets executed later)? How can I measure how long the reflow/repaint is taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript execution usually does not block for reflow.  Usually repaints or reflows are queued and then the browser processes all queued up actions when the current thread of JS execution finishes.  This is because it is more efficient to do one layout after all JS modifications are done than to do a relayout after every single change.  So, normally a layout will not occur during your timer.

There are some properties which you could request in your Javascript which rely on an accurately laid out page (not painted though) and requesting those properties can force a layout in the middle of your JS which would show up in the timers.  See [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en) for some details on what can force a layout in the middle of your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As per w3.org, `performance.now` does not include the time spent on repaints/on-screen rendering.

> NOTE:As the now method returns the current time, time spent while a document is hidden [Page Visibility] or not fully active [HTML5] is included for the purpose of this method - [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#dom-performance-now).